# How do i get About ME Data of user from Google?

Tags: php, json, google-plus

How can I get "About Me" data from Google Plus or Google profiles using PHP API? I want to get user name, location, about me etc (the information displayed on the user's screen). Also I want to get its feeds. Please help me with or without code.

Answer (score 1):

You should start with the [Google+ PHP quickstart sample](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/php) to see how to connect a user to your application using the Google+ API and then perform API calls. The relevant API call for retrieving a user's profile data is plus.people.get('me') - in PHP it is:

```
$user = $plus->people->get('me');
error_log($user['displayName']);
```

As far as "feed" data is concerned, the Google+ API allows you to retrieve the public activities for a user using plus.activities.list. In PHP the API call would be:

```
$activities = $plus->activities->listActivities('me', 'public');
error_log('Activities are: ' . print_r($activities,true));
```

Note that the data you are retrieving in both these cases is going to be restricted to what that user has made publicly visible.